# WIreless and wired networking no longer working after update today (Jan 31) of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, updates

I just did an update of my Ubuntu install on my laptop and after rebooting, the wireless didn't work anymore, it doesn't even show up in iwconfig, however it does show up in lspci (Broadcom BCM43228). I then tried to connect the laptop to a wired connection, it gets an IP address from the router using DHCP successfully, however the internet does not work at all, I can't even ping my router and I cannot get to any website.

Also, if I go to system settings->sofware&updates->additional drivers, the Broadcome driver shows up, however, if i try to click on "do not use this device" and then "apply", it just switches back to "Using Broadcom 802.11.." ignoring my change.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kernel are you using `uname -a` in terminal will tell

Comment: Thanks for your interest,
the kernel is 2.13.0-45-generic (installed Jan13)

I did a look at the packages updated/installed and i see software-properties-common:amd64 and software-properties-gtk:amd64 were installed, amongst other things.

Comment: I think it is likely 3.13.0-45, so what is the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: Yea,  3.13.0-45. lspci command gives:   
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359] Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [13e4:0607].   

The ethernet controller also shows up [0200]: realtek ....

Comment: So what is the wired ethernet?  Both wired and wireless usually show up along with the kernel drivers used with that command

Comment: Alright, I got the wired networking working (I had a static IP setup, but with DHCP it now works).

Here is the output:  
root@PhilTwist:~# lspci -nnk|grep -iA2 net
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
 Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0607]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2205]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your wired is working, try sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source and reboot, your wifi should work if the ethernet cable is unplugged.

Since that didn't work, reboot and hold the shift key, when the grub menu appears, select advanced options or previous versions and select the 3.13.0-43 kernel to boot into as I don't know what Ubuntu did in the latest kernel
......

Comment: Doesn't work. At first I got a msg to do apt-get autoremove, which I did. Then when I run the line you mentioned I get:

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded

I tried a reboot anyway, still nothing changed, and iwconfig shows nothing:

root@PhilTwist:~# iwconfig eth0 no wireless extensions.

lo no wireless extensions.

Comment: I start with 3.13.0-44 and wifi works fine again. Thank you. Hopefully 3.13.0-46+ will fix this problem for me. I guess there is nothing else really to do to try to get things to work in 3.13.0-45?